# Find $P(0)$ when P is a polynomial function that's checking the validity of this equation: $P(0)+...+P(n)=n^5$ ,$n=0,1,..$

Tags: functions, polynomials

Let the polynomial function $\:P:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\:$ check the validity of the equation $\:P\left(0\right)+\:...\:+\:P\left(n\right)=n^5$ ,$\:n=0,1,...$ ;

Then $\:P\left(0\right)=$?

At first glance it was pretty obvious that the answer is $P(0)=0$. But then I discovered that this is not the right answer. Can someone show me the way this is supposed to be solved?

Comment: I'd suspect that the validity of the question is or in any case should be only assumed for $n=1, 2, \dots$ and not $n=0$. In which case the polynomial in the answer would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we would have $P(n)=n^5-(n-1)^5=5n^4-10n^3+10n^2-5n+1$. But that gives
$P(0)=1$ which rather scuppers the fact that $P(0)=0$.

Conclusion: there is no **polynomial** function $P$ that works.